# Get Last Date within Range for Each Id Group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let say I have a collection with the following item:

```
[{myId:0,date:01.01.17,data:1000},
 {myId:1,date:01.02.17,data:2000},
 {myId:0,date:01.03.17,data:3000},
 {myId:1,date:01.04.17,data:4000},
 {myId:0,date:01.05.17,data:5000}]
```

I want to create a query that get a date as a parameter and return an array with single object for evrey myId that have the maximum date bellow the requested one.

For example calling the query with 15.03.17 date return:

```
[{myId:1,date:01.02.17,data:2000},
 {myId:0,date:01.03.17,data:3000}]
```

And calling query with 15.01.17 date return

```
[{myId:0,date:01.01.17,data:1000}]
```

I'm looking for an answer that doesn't use db.eval

Comment: Certainly not going to use eval. Your data is not valid. You might mean strings, but you hopefully mean real BSON dates. So what does the data "really" look like?

Comment: `{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59f9d0f43400ed4e42d908ac"),
        "fid" : 1,
        "data" : {amount:100},
        "date" : ISODate("2017-11-01T13:49:40.003Z")
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing your data to make it valid:

```
db.junk.insertMany([
 {myId:0,date: new Date("2017-01-01"),data:1000},
 {myId:1,date: new Date("2017-02-01"),data:2000},
 {myId:0,date: new Date("2017-03-01"),data:3000},
 {myId:1,date: new Date("2017-04-01"),data:4000},
 {myId:0,date: new Date("2017-05-01"),data:5000}
])
```

You run an aggregate statement, filtering the entries via [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), then applying [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) to ensure the order and using [`$last`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) for the "max" on each grouping boundary:

```
db.junk.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "date": { "$lte": new Date("2017-03-15") } } },
  { "$sort": { "date": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$myId",
    "date": { "$last": "$date" },
    "data": { "$last": "$data" }  
  }}
])
```

Returns:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "data" : 2000.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 0.0,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "data" : 3000.0
}
```

And for the other date:

```
db.junk.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "date": { "$lte": new Date("2017-01-15") } } },
  { "$sort": { "date": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$myId",
    "date": { "$last": "$date" },
    "data": { "$last": "$data" }  
  }}
])
```

Returns:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 0.0,
    "date" : ISODate("2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "data" : 1000.0
}
```

If you really must you can add a [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) as the final pipeline stage in order to ensure the order of `_id` ( `myId` value ) returned:

```
db.junk.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "date": { "$lte": new Date("2017-03-15") } } },
  { "$sort": { "date": 1 } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$myId",
    "date": { "$last": "$date" },
    "data": { "$last": "$data" }  
  }},
  { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
])
```